# Swaping elements of two lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list, swap

I try to find a way to swap elements of two lists which are in the following format:

```
l1=[[(x1,x2),(x3,x4),...],[(xk,xl),(xm,xn),...],...]
l2=[[y1,y2,y3,...],[yk,yl,ym,...],...]
```

How can I swap y1 with x2, y2 with x4, which is swap y_k with x_2k ,which increments linearly?

List Examples:

```
l1=[[('Al', 'NNP'), ('-', 'HYPH'), ('Zaman', 'NNP'), (':', ':')]]
l2=[['PROPN', 'PUNCT', 'PROPN', 'PUNCT']]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Are l1 and l2 are nested lists ?

Comment: Can you give us actual lists as an example, things we can copy and paste into Python, and that cover any edge cases? It's hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do from this vague description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do any *truly* in-place swaps, because the first list contains tuples, which are immutable, but you can replace the tuples with new tuples that contain the swapped element.

```
for xs, ys in zip(l1, l2):
    for i in range(len(xs)):
        x = xs[i][1]
        y = ys[i]
        xs[i] = (xs[i][0], y)
        ys[i] = x
```

Or if you really wanted to be terse, you can do one-line, simultaneous swaps in python.

```
xs[i], ys[i] = (xs[i][0], ys[i]), xs[i][1]
```